# Boost installation validation

Tags: c++, boost

What is the easiest way to verify boost has been installed? I did try to manually find the files but being a Linux newbie I wasn't able to.

I wasn't sure if there was a one-line command check?

Comment: try `find /usr/lib/ -iname 'libboost*' -print` or `find /lib/ -iname 'libboost*' -print` on the terminal if you are using linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to compile a simple program:

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

int main() { }
```

You can also look for the boost header files in `/usr/include/boost/`, and perhaps also in `/usr/local/include/` in case someone has installed a local (non-distribution) version.

Parallelly, you can/need to check `/usr/lib` (or `/usr/local/lib`) for the compiled libraries that go with Boost such as `libboost_system.so`.

If you know `cmake`, you can check out its `FindBoost` module to see what sort of checks they do to discover the location of a potential boost installation.

Comment: I went to compile a program but the article i was following for help used the path of the boost libraries in the compile command (is this normal? if it is, then your method wouldn't work as i wouldnt be able to compile if i need to know the directory to compile)

Comment: There's no magic to tell you *where* Boost is installed (many versions could be installed simultaneously in different places). The best you can do is use a heuristic to try a few places and otherwise rely on a user paramter (e.g. `--with-boost=/opt/local/`).